# Android Studio autocomplete shows same layout view ID twice

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions

When using the autocompletion feature, I suddenly see every layout view ID twice. How can I only show each ID one time in the autocomplete popup?

Note, I am importing the `activity_main.xml` layout like this:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

[Autocomplete two instances of each ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgGlD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing a `Clean` and `Rebuild` would help (in the `Build` menu), or `Invalidate Caches and Restart` in the `File` menu.

But just so you know, *Kotlin Android Extensions* (including the *synthetics* you're using) is deprecated and unsupported, so it's possible you might see screwy behaviour like this in the tooling. You might just have to put up with it if you continue to use it - the recommended replacement is *View Binding*, and there's some info about it here (and how to migrate from *synthetics*) [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Comment: The View Binding migration solved the issue, thanks!